# Нужна ли запятая: "Сбежали, негодяи!"?

Tags: пунктуация

*"Они ушли! Сбежали, негодяи!"*

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после слова "сбежали"? К какому правилу относится этот случай? На запятую с обращением не похоже, так как предложение обращено не к сбежавшим.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна.

Здесь действует следующее правило Розенталя:
Обособленное приложение может относиться к отсутствующему в данном предложении местоимению или существительному, если последнее подсказывается контекстом, например: *Дитя сама, в толпе детей играть и прыгать не любила* (Пушкин) (подразумевается личное местоимение *она*, т.е. Татьяна). *А что касается до обеда — у меня, брат, есть на примете придворный официант: так, собака, накормит, что просто не встанешь* (Гоголь) (т.е. «так он, собака, накормит...»).
Отсутствующее местоимение может подсказываться личной формой глагола-сказуемого, например: *Никогда, грешница, не пью, а через такой случай выпью* (Чехов).

Comment: oleedd, только не следовало бы перевирать цитату из Пушкина: классик всё-таки))

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Это не я, а Розенталь и Былинский.

Comment: Ну им тоже не следовало перевирать) Тем более, там рифма.

Comment: @oleedd Безоговорочно следую вашим призывам и требую, как это любите вы, точности в ответе. **Где**, в каком из справочников Розенталя имеется указанный вами кусочек: *...прыгать не **любила***? Дайте ссылку!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Требую не точности, а правильности. Как люблю я? Только одно было к вам и другим (про указание лучшего варианта). Это из оригинального справочника — "Трудные случаи пунктуации" 1959. То, что в Интернете, — сокращённая и переделанная версия. Вы же в библиотеке работаете, может, у вас там есть второе издание, оно самое ценное (у меня его нет). Было бы это с сайта, в ответе была бы ссылка.

Comment: "Дык" так и написали бы (Розенталь, название, год, печатный вариант), потому при невозможности проверить приходится только удивляться. / В Эстонии, в муниципальной библиотеке, 1959 год? Это вряд ли — даже интересоваться не пойду. / Я когда-то попросила оставлять — мне передают, если люди приносят "прошлый век" или что-то списывается. / Просто я работаю в *одном здании* с библиотекой.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Розенталь иногда менял классику. Не раз сталкивался. В основном сокращение (примеры гораздо чётче становятся). Были и пунктуационные изменения (например, где "старик, одержимый рисунком").